# Is "Use A Framework" a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-quality, comments-as-answers

In the same vein of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

I'm starting to see answers (won't name names) for very simple or fundamental questions that are using the old "Use x framework!" answer, almost without considering the question. If someone has a basic SQL question, I really don't think that "Use a framework!" should be an encouraged answer. As much as I love overhead, I don't think changing architecture and line of thinking to accomplish one inner join is a high quality answer. At best it could be a point to consider in a larger answer.

I'm not a huge down-voter but I think a down-vote for these suggestions is warranted.

Comment: You should downvote any answer that is not helpful or does not answer the question. As Robert says, if the answer is merely "use framework x", then it deserves a downvote. Otherwise, with a bit more elaboration, it's probably OK. Don't be afraid to cast downvotes, though. They're very useful in ensuring that the *best* answers appear at the top of the page (and in fact, are specifically designed for this purpose).

Answer (score 22):

*"Use a framework"* is not a valid answer, it is a comment.

However, *"[This particular framework] should solve your problem.  Here is a code example that will accomplish what you want"* is a valid answer.

Comment: And although it shouldn't really be necessary to point this out, the code sample needs to actually *solve the problem*, not just illustrate that the framework exists and does similar things.

Comment: Awesome. I just think it is such an unhelpful answer to people who'd rather have a firm understanding of _what_ frameworks do, which has a tendency to get lost.