# Ok to answer using another framework?

Tags: discussion

Let's say that a question is for a specific framework/library.

Is it OK to give an answer which solves the problem but using another framework/library?

Both in the same area (like OR/M or IoC containers).

Comment: Related, *maybe* (big maybe) duplicate: [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: Or to put it extremely exaggerated: *Is it okay to answer a Windows question with the Linux solution?*

Comment: @GardenGnobobby: No way near. Your first comment is more related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104048/is-use-a-framework-a-valid-answer?rq=1. And your second comment is very broad and the programming implications is very big. An answer using another library/framework might give the developer a better solution for the specific problem.

Comment: `And your second comment is very broad and the programming implications is very big.` And "use another framework" is not?

Comment: No. For instance using Unity instead of Autofac is a lot less job than switching from windows to linux ;)

Comment: And from Unity to DirectX?

Comment: yes it is fine, logic remains same,only syntax changes, but make sure do not do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10829708/996493) kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to give an answer which solves the problem but using another framework/library?

Is it OK?  Of course it is!  Its a valid answer.

The fact that it might not be useful to the OP is important as he might not accept that as an answer.  However if this alternative framework solves the problem then it might help someone else in the future facing the same issue.

Unless the OP has **specifically** stated that there are some limitations (IE. It **has** to be a solution within the current framework) then posting an answer that suggests a different framework is...well... not very helpful...

Comment: I honestly disagree. If I ask a question for jQuery, I do not want an answer for Prototype and vice versa. Same goes for bigger stuff, like .NET and Java and Operating Systems. [And languages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94121/should-we-close-vb-net-questions-as-duplicates-of-c-questions-and-likewise).

Comment: `"Unless the OP has specifically stated that there are some limitations"` - tags on questions are not binding.  Unless a specific limitation has been specified then its a 100% valid answer...

Comment: @gar - Oh... its you :P  hehe - another confusing username change for me to wrap my head around :S

Comment: Hehe. ;P Just wait another four days and I can change it again...just not sure to what... ;P

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends quite a bit on the question, and how easy it would be to extrapolate.

For a (Java) DI/IoC example, providing an answer using Guice injections and AOP, without a fairly detailed explanation, would be essentially useless to someone looking for a Spring XML solution.

Even a small jQuery answer might involve moderate hoopage to translate to something usable in pure JS, or a JS framework that uses very different syntax or mechanisms. Other times it might be a trivial translation, and would be considered "close enough".

If it's a *theoretical* question, the technicalities of an answer might not matter at all.